# Accessing aliases inside a select

Tags: postgresql, sql-view

I'm trying to create a view with some derived data, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

```
create or replace view myview as
SELECT 
    SUM(field1) AS "field1",
    COUNT(field1) AS "field2",
    (field1/field2) AS "field3"
FROM mytable
```

My problem is I'm more familiar with mysql and could probably figure this out, but this is postgres and I am still getting tripped up on syntax.

I'd like field3 to be based on fields 1 and 2. I'm guessing I can do something like...

```
(SUM(field1)/COUNT(field1)) AS "field3"
```

But that feels redundant, my my actual query is must longer, so accessing the alias would be idea if there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

The alias isnt recognize on the same level. Either you repeat the code as you suggest. Or you need create a subquery.

```
SELECT (field1/field2) AS "field3"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(field1) AS "field1",
        COUNT(field1) AS "field2",        
    FROM mytable
    ) T
```